# Use Matplotlib Plot and Widgets in function and return user input

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

My problem is the following:

I create a Matplotlib figure including some widget sliders and a button to close the figure. This works. What can I do to use this code inside a function which returns e.g. the values of the slides AFTER clicking the "close figure" button?

Here is the code (im3d is a 3d image numpy array):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

class IndexTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, data3d, title):
        self.ax = ax
        ax.set_title(title)

        self.data3d = data3d
        rows, cols, self.slices = data3d.shape
        self.ind = self.slices//2

        self.im = ax.imshow(self.data3d[:, :, self.ind])
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.im.set_data(self.data3d[:, :, self.ind])
        ax.set_ylabel('slice %s' % self.ind)
        self.im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
#
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='b')
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

tracker1 = IndexTracker(ax, im3d, 'Select First Image')
tracker2 = IndexTracker(ax2, im3d, 'Select Last Image')

def slider_changed(value, tracker):
    numb = int(round(value))    
    tracker.ind = numb    
    tracker.update()

max0 = im3d.shape[2] -1

ax_start  = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.85, 0.35, 0.03])
sl_start = Slider(ax_start, 'START', 0, max0, valinit=0, valfmt="%i")

ax_end  = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.85, 0.35, 0.03])
sl_end = Slider(ax_end, 'END', 0, max0, valinit=0, valfmt="%i")

def sl_start_changed(val):
    slider_changed(sl_start.val,tracker1)

def sl_end_changed(val):
    slider_changed(sl_end.val,tracker2)

sl_start.on_changed(sl_start_changed)
sl_end.on_changed(sl_end_changed)

class Index(object):

    def close_figure(self, event):
        plt.close(fig)    

callback = Index()
ax_button = fig.add_axes([0.7, 0.06, 0.15, 0.075])
button = Button(ax_button, 'DONE')
button.on_clicked(callback.close_figure)
fig.canvas.manager.window.raise_()

plt.plot()
```

My first idea was to run a while loop after plt.plot(), something like this:

```
while not_done:
   time.sleep(0.5)
```

and change not_done to False inside the function close_figure. But in this case, the plot doesn't show.

Comment: Please provide your source code so we have something to go from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider is still available after the figure is closed. Hence you can just access its `val` attribute after closing the figure

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

slider = Slider(...)

# .. callbacks

plt.show() # you may use plt.show(block=True) when this is run in interactive mode

print(slider.val)
```

---

Edit after clarifications:

You are running spyder and use the IPython console within. This has several implications.

- You need to turn interactive mode off, `plt.ioff()`
- You need to deactivate "support" for matplotlib

[image]

Then the following code runs fine and only prints the values after the figure is closed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

plt.ioff()

im3d = np.random.rand(20,20,10)


class IndexTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, data3d, title):
        self.ax = ax
        ax.set_title(title)

        self.data3d = data3d
        rows, cols, self.slices = data3d.shape
        self.ind = self.slices//2

        self.im = ax.imshow(self.data3d[:, :, self.ind])
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.im.set_data(self.data3d[:, :, self.ind])
        ax.set_ylabel('slice %s' % self.ind)
        self.im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
#
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='b')
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

tracker1 = IndexTracker(ax, im3d, 'Select First Image')
tracker2 = IndexTracker(ax2, im3d, 'Select Last Image')

def slider_changed(value, tracker):
    numb = int(round(value))    
    tracker.ind = numb    
    tracker.update()

max0 = im3d.shape[2] -1

ax_start  = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.85, 0.35, 0.03])
sl_start = Slider(ax_start, 'START', 0, max0, valinit=0, valfmt="%i")

ax_end  = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.85, 0.35, 0.03])
sl_end = Slider(ax_end, 'END', 0, max0, valinit=0, valfmt="%i")

def sl_start_changed(val):
    slider_changed(sl_start.val,tracker1)

def sl_end_changed(val):
    slider_changed(sl_end.val,tracker2)

sl_start.on_changed(sl_start_changed)
sl_end.on_changed(sl_end_changed)

class Index(object):

    def close_figure(self, event):
        plt.close(fig)    

callback = Index()
ax_button = fig.add_axes([0.7, 0.06, 0.15, 0.075])
button = Button(ax_button, 'DONE')
button.on_clicked(callback.close_figure)
fig.canvas.manager.window.raise_()

plt.show()

print(sl_start.val, sl_end.val)
```

Alternatively, you may just run the complete code in external command line, without the need for `plt.ioff()`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this I know. But how do I get the program to halt after plt.show(), let the user interact with the figure and proceed with print(slider.val) only after the figure closing?

Comment: The value is only printed after the figure is closed.

Comment: Not on my machine. If I wrap the above code in    def my_function(im3d): .......     return sl_start.val,sl_end.val     The function returns before I close the figure.

Comment: What happens if you put `plt.ioff()` in the beginning of the code? In general the more we know about where and how you run the code, which versions are is use etc the higher the probability for a solution that works for you.

Comment: With plt.ioff() the plot doesn't show at all. I use python 3.6.3 and IPython 6.1.0.

Comment: It might have to do with my Graphics backend, (I use Qt5 in Spyder). This example https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/lasso_selector_demo.html should do something similar to what I want. If I run this code, the matplotlib figure window opens, but doesn't render and the coder after plt.draw() executes.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. The example in my last comment is still not running but nevermind...

Comment: The example should at least work as it is with the "Execute in external system terminal" option. If it isn't that may be a different issue.